# Getting the Item of Array by name of param

Tags: javascript

```
for (...) {
    files.push(files[i]);
    li_out.push({name : fileName, list_files : files});
}
```

How to get the Array of list_files by name?

```
var list_files_of_file3 = li_out[name == "file3" (?????)].list_files;
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) can be used in this case.

```
var list_files_of_file3 = li_out.find(o => o.name === "file3").list_files;
```

```js
// Variable names changed for DEMO purpose

var files = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    files.push({
        name: 'fileName ' + i,
        list_files: 'something ' + i
    });
}

var res = files.find(o => o.name === 'fileName 3').list_files;

console.log(res);
```

Comment: If the item to find may not exist in the array `(files.find(o => o.name === 'fileName 1003') || {}).list_files`.

Comment: And how to update the list? 
   `list_files_of_file3.push("file3a");
    li_out[name == "file3"].list_files = list_files_of_file3;`

Comment: @user2011909 Yes, the object is the reference of the actual element in the array, so you can change the object and the array will be updated. Check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u6wrt0a1/)

Answer (score 3):

> How to get the Array of list_files by name?

using `filter`, try

```
var result = li_out.filter(function(item){ return item.name == "file3" });
```

> Is it also possible to just return a property of the matching items
>   instead of the whole object? (below comment @MajidFouladpour)

Once you have got the result

```
var propertyNames = result.map(function(obj){ return obj.propertName; })
```

Comment: Is it also possible to just return a property of the matching items instead of the whole object?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour sure which property?

Comment: Let's say `item` has a `size` property, instead of returning an array of matching items, could we return an array of just `size`s of the matching items?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour sure, try the suggested code above